# Difference between #define DATA 10 and # if defined DATA

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have seen in many place we are validating the statement like

```
 # if defined(DATA ) || defined(__hpux) || defined(__sun)
```

My doubt is: what is meaning of only `define` like `#defined DATA` and checking in the condition?

Comment: sorry what don't you understand specifically here? You've posted some `#if` macros but your title and question is different as `#define` is different to `#if defined` so what don't you understand

Comment: Do note that the code is using [`defined`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html#Defined), not `define`.

Comment: Is it like if we have defined the value in other file and check the same value in other file

Comment: Yes-ish, You're checking to see if a symbol has been defined.

Comment: Are you asking what `defined(DATA)` _means_ to the preprocessor? Or what the preprocessor is at all? Or where `DATA` was (maybe) defined? Or something else?

Comment: Your question isn't clear because you use `#defined DATA` in the text which is invalid C.  You could use `#define DATA` or `#if defined DATA` and it might make sense.  Fundamentally, you're asking about what defines `DATA` and what tests whether `DATA` is defined — two radically different though somewhat related operations.  It isn't clear why either should cause confusion.

Answer (score 6):

These definitions are used to conditionally compile code.

If you check like this

```
#if defined(A)
#endif
```

Then it does not matter if you defined it with

```
#define A
```

or

```
#define A 1
```

In both cases the macro is defined and `#ifdef A` or `#if defined (A)` will result in `TRUE`.

On the other hand if you test using

```
#if A
#endif
```

Then you will get the `TRUE` if `A` is defined and non-zero and you will get `FALSE` if `A` is not defined.

---

This causes a potential pitfall.
You need to be consistent with the way you use your macros throughout your code!

If you intent to enable/disable a feature with defining a macro to either `0` or `1` you need to check with the second variant:

```
#define A 0

#if A
  .. enabled
#else
  .. disabled  <<<< We go here if A is defined as 0
#endif
```

If you accidentally check with `#ifdef` in one place, you will get unexpected result:

```
#define A 0

#ifdef A
  .. enabled  <<<< We go here if A is 0 (and for any other value of A)!!
#else
  .. disabled
#endif
```

This can cause some confusion.

Comment: Reminder:  Some compilers allow for defining macros at compiler invocation.  The option "-D" or "-d" is common for defining symbols.

Comment: Also, some compilers also provide their own special symbols.  This allows for a source code to check the compiler or platform.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, sure. But in which way is this related?

Comment: Because you have `#define` in your code examples.  The code may not have a `#define` and rely on the symbol being defined by the compiler or passed to the compiler.  I'm not saying your examples are incorrect, but expanding the scope.  For example, `__hpux` is most likely not defined in any files, but internally by the compiler.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are right. I understand the question in a way, that the author wants to know difference between macros with replacement text and without. And the way of checking these macros. Therefore I don't think the source for the macro definition is important. But I may be wrong, of course.

Answer (score 0):

"#defined var" alone would have no logical effect. It behaves as a statement.
It is equivalent to having a line "i == 1;", given i is initiated previously.

Please make sure that your question is clear and unambiguous next time. Good luck